# Sencha Ext JS4.. [Grid ActionColumn] doesn't display

Tags: extjs4, extjs

I'm new with sencha js 4. I already followed the instruction from the sencha documentation guide regarding with how to use `actioncolumn`, but it doesn't display on my grid.

"Where did I miss?. is there anything that I skipped? or is there anything that I didn't included? help.."

I use the `kitchenSink` sample that sencha provided me. I tried to manipulate it and added an `actioncolumn` from one of the grids in the `kitchenSink` sample

Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('PayrollLite.view.GridExample', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

frame: true,
width: 1200,
height: 750,

store: 'Employees',

columns: 
[
    { text: 'Employee Code', width: '10%', dataIndex: 'EmployeeCode' },
    { text: 'Last Name', width: '22%', dataIndex: 'LastName'},
    { text: 'First Name', width: '25%', dataIndex: 'FirstName' },
    { text: 'Middle Name', width: '15%', dataIndex: 'MiddleName' },
    { text: 'Position', width: '15%', dataIndex: 'PositionID', sortable: false },
    {
        xtype:'actioncolumn',
        width:50,
        items: [{
            icon: 'extjs/examples/shared/icons/fam/cog_edit.png',  // Use a URL in the icon config
            tooltip: 'Edit',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                alert("Edit " + rec.get('firstname'));
            }
        },{
            icon: 'extjs/examples/restful/images/delete.png',
            tooltip: 'Delete',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                alert("Terminate " + rec.get('firstname'));
            }
        }]
    }
]
});
```

Comment: sry, I mean.. what's wrong with my code does it lack some requirements? or is it syntax error?  thats why it doesnt display anything.

?_?

Comment: My Question is.. "Why is it doesnt display the actioncolumn that I inserted in the grid items??"

Comment: Feel free to edit your post to add that clarification.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be the widths - try setting the other columns to flex widths instead. Like so:

```
Ext.define('PayrollLite.view.GridExample', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

frame: true,
width: 1200,
height: 750,

store: 'Employees',

columns: 
[
    { text: 'Employee Code', flex: '1', dataIndex: 'EmployeeCode' },
    { text: 'Last Name', flex: '2.2', dataIndex: 'LastName'},
    { text: 'First Name', flex: '2.5', dataIndex: 'FirstName' },
    { text: 'Middle Name', flex: '1.5', dataIndex: 'MiddleName' },
    { text: 'Position', flex: '1.5', dataIndex: 'PositionID', sortable: false },
    {
        xtype:'actioncolumn',
        width:50,
        items: [{
            icon: 'extjs/examples/shared/icons/fam/cog_edit.png',  // Use a URL in the icon config
            tooltip: 'Edit',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                alert("Edit " + rec.get('firstname'));
            }
        },{
            icon: 'extjs/examples/restful/images/delete.png',
            tooltip: 'Delete',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                alert("Terminate " + rec.get('firstname'));
            }
        }]
    }
]
});
```